# Wake from shutdown for Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Is there any way to wake up macbook pro on LAN magic packet from shutdown state ? I know it's possible to wake from sleep, but I need to wake from complete shutdown. I'm using both MacOS and Windows 7.

Update: Sorry, for previously wrong description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Wake on LAN works when asleep as the components are not fully shut down, and when receiving the packet to wake up the MacBook can respond promptly. Shutting down powers down the components, and thus waking on LAN is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

On my computer, I had to enable **Power On By PCI Devices** and **Power On By PCIe Devices** in BIOS to have WOL from shutdown. Additionally, I had to enable **Wake from Shutdown** in Windows in *Device Manager > Right-click on my NIC > Properties > Advanced* tab. I don't know how to enable those options on a Mac, but hopefully this little hint would get you started.

Comment: The question was exactly about Macbook.

Comment: @Michael: You mentioned: "I'm using both MacOS and Windows 7." I believe you only need to enable 'Wake from Shutdown' in Windows. I don't know what to adjust on the OS X part, but as I said, you could treat my hint as a starting point.

Comment: The setting is not much depending on OS, it's rather ethernet card/driver capability which can be set in any OS.